# What's the attribute/property/field of a System.Threading.Thread which corresponds with Process Explorer's TID?

Tags: c#, multithreading, process-explorer

I'm currently trying to see what's happening with a thread, I've created in a C# application. The thread is of type `System.Threading.Thread` and is embedded inside an internal object (and I have access to the thread inside that object while debugging).

I'm checking the application, using "[Process Explorer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/process-explorer)".
Process Explorer has a "Threads" tab with columns "TID", "CPU", "Cycles Delta", "Suspend Count" and "Start Address".
In order to identify the thread I've started (in the debugger), I believe I can look for either the TID (Thread ID) or the start address, where I believe the thread ID to be the clearest.

However, at first sight I don't see any property/field/attribute in the `System.Threading.Thread` class which looks like a thread ID.

Does anybody know which attribute/property/field of `System.Threading.Thread` corresponds with Process Explorer's TID column?

**Edit:** there seems to be a `ManagedThreadId` but that's not it.

Comment: https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/blob/master/Documentation/botr/threading.md

Comment: @TheGeneral: from your comment I see that there's a difference between managed threads and native ones, so as Process Explorer only looks at native threads and I'm creating a managed thread, I should not be using Process Explorer for this purpose. Can you tell me which tool I can use for verifying if my thread is still running or not?

Comment: Is the threading window not giving you the information you need in visual studio ? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/walkthrough-debugging-a-multithreaded-application?view=vs-2019

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Essentially, *Managed Threads* are not *Native Threads*, looking for a correlation in *Task Manager* will not be suitable. For more information see [CLR Threading Overview - Managed vs. Native Threads](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/blob/master/Documentation/botr/threading.md)

> Managed code executes on "managed threads," which are distinct from
> the native threads provided by the operating system. A native thread
> is a thread of execution of native code on a physical machine; a
> managed thread is a virtual thread of execution on the CLR's virtual
> machine.
>
> ...

However, if you are using Visual studio you can use the *Thread Window* to debug managed threads.

[View threads in the Visual Studio debugger by using the Threads window (C#, Visual Basic, C++)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/walkthrough-debugging-a-multithreaded-application?view=vs-2019)

> Several Visual Studio user interface elements help you debug
> multithreaded apps. This article introduces multithreaded debugging
> features in the code editor window, Debug Location toolbar, and
> Threads window

[Walkthrough: Debug a multithreaded app using the Threads window (C#, Visual Basic, C++](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/how-to-use-the-threads-window?view=vs-2019)

> Visual Studio provides several tools and user interface elements to
> help you debug multithreaded applications. This tutorial shows how to
> use thread markers, the Parallel Stacks window, the Parallel Watch
> window, conditional breakpoints, and filter breakpoints. Completing
> this tutorial will familiarize you with Visual Studio features for
> debugging multithreaded applications.